# Install executable drivers on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, sound, wine, executable

I downloaded Ubuntu to my old pc and I want to install audio drivers on it.But I cant find a  file for Ubuntu I can only download executable files (I tried Wine).
Link to my pc:https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/hu/en/products/desktops-and-all-in-ones/thinkcentre-m-series-desktops/thinkcentre-m58p/downloads/driver-list/component?name=Audio

Comment: One of the most important things for you to realize is that Linux is not Windows. Take those last four words and paste them into a search engine of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can't install Windows drivers on Linux, nor would that make any sense. On Linux, device drivers typically come directly with the kernel -- with a few notable exceptions such as the proprietary NVidia binary drivers.

For Lenovo you can be pretty sure that the kernel already has the best and latest audio drivers and even firmware.

If you have any problems with your audio setup on Linux, please edit your question to add more details about that.

If you just wanted to be a good citizen and just wanted to make sure you have the latest and best drivers (like you always have to do manually on Windows), rest assured that on Linux you already did your civic duty by keeping the system updated. ;-)